# Dryer display fogged up

Tags: dryer, laundry

[image]

I got a brand new maytag dryer and I accidentally had the exhaust vent blocked for the first cycle and the room got a bit humid and the display fogged up like this. I fixed the problem, but it's been 30 minutes and the display is still like this. Will it ever get fixed or did I ruin it forever? What can I do? Thank you

Comment: The dryer vent runs outside, right? Or are we dealing with a condensing dryer here? (i.e. it has a drain pipe running out of it instead of a vent pipe)

Comment: It's been a little while longer now. Is it still fogged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should actually dry out in a few hours, maybe a day or two. It's just condensation and it should clear up. If it was an older machine, I'd say to unscrew the front cover and go in with a Q-tip and wipe it down but since it's a new machine and under warranty, you don't want to be taking anything apart unless you're really careful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, I notice that the laundry room gets sort of warm and still a little bit humid when the dryer is running. Is that normal? It's vented with a normal aluminum vent hose that is tightly attached to both ends of the vent and seems to be working. It's worth noting that the room itself has no ventilation once you close the door.

Comment: @Dryerman Did you thoroughly clean out the vent and pipe before replacing the dryer?  Yes, a room with no ventilation will get a little humid with the dryer going.... after all, you're drying wet clothes... every time you check the lint tray, which you should do really often, you're letting humid air out. Think about adding some ventilation.